# Input text align issue in Firefox Mobile

Tags: css

I'm getting display issues when aligning input text to the right in Firefox Mobile for Android:

[image]

[image]

How it **should** display (See the padding Firefox Mobile adds):

[image]

This error seems to happen everywhere, not only with `placeholders` but with `values` at well.

I tried explicitly aligning the placeholder:

```
input:-moz-placeholder { text-align:right; }
```

With direction:

```
direction: rtl;
```

And tried removing padding.

It's not a usability problem but I'd be a nice thing to get it display normally.

Has any encountered the same issue?

**EDIT:** I'm already using `text-align: right;`. It works in every browser but FF mobile.

Comment: Can you please make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) of your problem? Have you tried setting the `text-align` property on the input itself?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I updated the question and also uploaded a screenshot of what I'm expecting. See the padding FF adds at the right of the right aligned input.